# php file download progress bar with/without using jquery or ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am preparing one application in which I need to so the progress bar for downloading file.

I have script which show progress bar for uploading file.
But how to show progress bar for downloading file.

I am using php and I want to know how can we create progress bar which show the amount of file downloaded.

Any script ?

Comment: Try the answer in this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022958/how-would-you-create-a-progress-bar-with-ajax-jquery-for-downloading-xml-content

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are many you can refer to this:  [Click Here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Progress-Bar-Plugin-CSS3/)